# Происхождение слов «боярин» и «барин»

Tags: этимология, лексика

Сразу напрашивается, что это родственные слова: мне кажется, слово "барин" — это как бы урезанный вариант слова "боярин". Правда ли это?
А еще мне интересно, что за слово "боярин"? Слово, видимо, русское, но никаких ассоциаций оно не вызывает. Или же оно пришло в русский язык от варягов и еще каких-то "интуристов"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

..Ну как-же не вызывает.. Корень "бой" к устаревшим явно не относится.
Изначально "боярин"="воин". Так называли не знатных дружинников и "простых" воинов, "живущих от меча".
Момент "перехода значения" назвать затрудняюсь, Но при Иване Грозном бояре подразделялись на "служилых", "поместных" и "удельных". Первые - зарабатывали на жизнь службой Государю или другим боярам ("боярские дети"), вторые - имели доход с земли, жалованной Государем за службу, третьи - владели наследными уделами.

Comment: А про барина не знаете?

Comment: ..Типичный образчик армейского жаргона.. Сокращение слова "боярин" для ускоренного произношения. Стало общеупотребительным "с подачи" "боевых холопов" (боярские слуги, сопровождавшие хозяина в походах). В связи с этим - получило значение "господин, хозяин".

Comment: Боярин, вероятно, от б(в)ой- воин, яр- лучший. Лучших, достойных дружинников коназа назначали на различные должности, когда верховный аз стал князем.

Comment: Зачем "плодить сущности"? Корень "бой" - общеславянский (читай - древний). Суффикс "-ар-" - активно используется. Суффикс "-ин-" - тоже. Почему Вас так тянет на изобретение слов?

Answer (score 4):

> Сразу напрашивается, что это родственные слова, то есть, как мне кажется, слово "барин" - это как бы урезанный вариант слова "боярин". Правда ли это?

Да. Это общепризнанный факт.

*Этимология*

*Восходит к др.-русск. форме бояринъ, которая заимствована из ст.-слав. болꙗринъ «вельможа», «боярин», слово дунайско-булгарского происхождения[1][2][3][4]. В церковнославянском языке употребляются как старая форма болѧринъ, так и более поздняя боѧринъ[5]. К др.-русск бояринъ восходит и сокращённая в бытовой речи форма баринъ, получившая общее значение «хозяин»[6].*

*Потомки боярских родов, записывались в родословные книги, боярские книги и боярские списки, некоторые из которых сохранились в государственных архивах. Многие происходили из княжеских родов, потерявших свои уделы и перешедших на службу к Великому князю, Царю, или королю, от которых они получали за службу уже новые земельные владения или поместья.*

(вики)

"Боярин", "Болярин" К слову "бой" не имеет отношения, вопреки расхожей версии. "Болярами" в дунайской Болгарии называли вельмож, как и на Руси - боярами.
Слово, видимо, тюркского происхождения, поскольку родственных связей ни в славянских, ни в греческом не прослеживается (а больше в исторической дунайской Болгарии ему взяться было неоткуда).

Кстати, само слово "бой" скорее всего в данной форме относительно позднее, изначально имело вид *оубой, убой* - со значением "убийство" - и уже поэтому не могло породить "боярин", форму же "убоярин" никто не фиксирует.

Comment: Слово "бой" - общеславянское. Обычно это трактуется как признак древности слова. Что же касается остального.. При Олеге (Вещем) этот термин уже использовался. И я с трудом представляю себе путь заимствования этого термина из тюркского в **то** время. Так-что славянская версия происхождения данного термина кажется мне более вероятной.

Comment: >При Олеге (Вещем) этот термин уже использовался.     
     
Подробнее можете? Какого слова? На чем Вы основываете утверждение?  
  
>Так-что славянская версия происхождения данного термина кажется мне более вероятной.     
    
>И я с трудом представляю себе путь заимствования этого термина из тюркского в то время     
      
Немудрено. Так все запутать, да еще Олега приплести. Историю болгар посмотрите. Там половина слов тюркских.

Comment: Слова Боярин. [Здесь](http://feb-web.ru/feb/slovenc/es/es1/es1-1541.htm) нашёл цитаты из Повести Временных Лет и новгородской летописи. По датировке - приблизительно оно и есть. Что же касается путей заимствования... Вы предлагаете считать, что в **те** времена культурные связи между Русью и Булгарией были настолько плотными, что русская элита "калькировала" самоназвание с булгарского? Мне корень "бой", суффикс "ар", указывающий на профессию, и окончание "ин", свидетельствующее о принадлежности к группе, кажутся более убедительными.

Comment: Когда повесть временных лет написана, не напомните? И в каком списке Вы её читали?   
  
Единственное, что я предлагаю, это не общаться более, пока Вы не перестанете фантазировать. Слишком много надо Вам разъяснять и из истории из из этимологии, а у меня нет времени.   
Форма "болярин" исключает все ваши изыски.
А все остальное - смотрите у серьезных авторов, хотя бы у Фасмера.

Comment: Связи  между  Киевской  Русью  и  Булгарией  на  Дунае  были  очень  плотными.  Святослав Игоревич  хотел  даже  сделать  Пловдив  столицей  своего  княжества.

Answer (score 2):

БОЯРИН

Боярин -  крупный землевладелец, представитель высшего слоя феодального общества.  Др.-рус. слово бояринъ (также боляринъ)  известно с дописьменной эпохи. Происхождение слова неясное, высказано множество версий, из них  внимания заслуживает следующее предположение.

Бояринъ  - это бояръ с суффиксом  -инъ, восходит к др-тюрк.  «boi  ar» - богатый/знатный муж. На славянской почве  (в Болгарии и Древней Руси)  слово подверглось доработке  и возможно, было сближено со словами «бой» и «болий» (большой). Предполагается, что в др.-болг. и  древневосточнославянском языках это слово появилось одновременно и, может быть, из одного источника.

БАРИН

Барин – это помещик по отношению к крепостным крестьянам или хозяин по отношению к прислуге. Слово  вошло в русский язык с середины 18 века, образовано от «боярин», сначала в обращении.  Для сравнения: госудАрь – сУдарь, также сокращение слова при обращении.

Comment: Бояре высшее сословие Роси и Руси после князя. Заимствовать название из языка чуждого, а то и враждебного- маловероятно. Аналог татаро-монгольского- мурза, мирза у тюрок.
Слово, видимо, от вой(бой) -воин, дружинник князя, -яр- лучший.
Князь, наделенный полной властью, раздавал должности своим приближенным, а ближе дружинников только семья князя.

Answer (score 0):

У нынешних осетин, потомков скифо-сармато-аланских племён, с которыми славяне имели плотный контакт, есть слово "бар", которое означает "право, полномочие принимать решение, поступать так, как считаешь нужным", и также "барин-господин", имеющий право на принятие любого решения.

Comment: Ну наверное все-таки не настолько плотный, чтобы заимствовать "родное" слово? Да и потом методом созвучия можно обосновать что угодно.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрим по "**Полному церковно-славянскому словарю**" магистра  Гр. Дьяченко , стр.57 / [ПЦСС](http://www.slavdict.narod.ru/_0057.htm) . Этот источник указывает древний вариант <<<БОЛЯРИН>> и считает , что слово <<<**БОЯРИН**>> по этимологии не славянское , а заимствованное : *венгерское* <<**bojar**>> - **герой** , *молдавско-валашское* <<**boiar**>> - **человек знатного происхождения** . Поэтому прав **@behemothus** , считающий , что  слово <<<**БОЯРИН**>>  не есть славянское .. Убедительно выглядит и мнение **@София** , что на Русь это слово пришло из Болгарии . К тому же , существует и болгарское имя <<<Бояр>> .  Но венгерская и румынская версия не выглядят более убедительно , чем тюркская , поскольку волжские тюрки появились на Балканах раньше , чем угры-мадьяры-печенеги , пришедшие в Центральную Европу с Востока  //////// Ещё одна ремарка . **@bernard** написал : "*Связи между Киевской Русью и Булгарией на Дунае были очень плотными. Святослав Игоревич хотел даже сделать Пловдив столицей своего княжества.*" Это весьма открытый исторический вопрос каким князем был Святослав Игоревич - киевским или болгарским . В ПВЛ много событий и личностей , перенесённых из Болгарии в Киевскую Русь . =========================================================================[image: бочрин-1.] [image: боярин-2.]                                                                 ========================================================================= Относительно <<**БАРИН**>> , то здесь может быть и сокращение от <<БОЯРИН>> и переделанное европейское <<БАРОН>> .

Answer (score 0):

БОЯР - состоит из 2 тюркских слов БАЙ (богатый) ЕР (мужчина). 
БАЙ ЕР - богатый мужчина. При произношении звучит БАЙЕР. Учитывая то, что боярами были в основном тюрки эта версия гораздо более правдоподобная и по смыслу соответствующая.
А версия БОЙ и ЯРЫЙ - это называется подогнали русский язык под тюркское слово. 
Именно при боярах в русский язык пришли такие тюркские слова как: Калпак, Сарафан, Каблук, Сундук, Кафтан и др.